# view queries made?

Tags: wp-query, query

I know I can use `get_num_queries()` for the number of queries. However, how can I see what queries Wordpress actually makes? I've tried using $query but that didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Save_queries_for_analysis).

in `wp-config.php`:

```
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
```

then in your template:

```
if (current_user_can('administrator')){
    global $wpdb;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($wpdb->queries);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

or without the above `SAVEQUERIES`, you can still see just the main query:

```
global $wp_query;
echo $wp_query->request;
```

or to see all of `$wp_query`:

```
<pre>
    <?php print_r($wp_query); ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: This is useful and the results are shocking, I can't understand why Wordpress makes soooo many useless queries

Answer (score 1):

There is another *low level* way of finding out what queries have been made throughout a request which was very useful for me in order to identify what was being inserted into the database upon submitting a form.

Basically what I did was one database dump before submitting the form, another database dump after submitting the form, then a diff of the two.

Although it may look too primitive, the result was exactly what I needed, without having to install any plugins or modify any code or `wp-config.php`.

The procedure I adopted was:

1. Get the form ready to submit, with all fields filled.
2. Do the first dump (change `user`, `pass` and `dbname` accordingly):

   `mysqldump -uuser -ppass dbname --skip-opt > /tmp/before.sql`
3. Submit the form.
4. Do the second dump (change `user`, `pass` and `dbname` accordingly):

   `mysqldump -uuser -ppass dbname --skip-opt > /tmp/after.sql`
5. Compare `before.sql` and `after.sql`, analyzing the result in `vim`:

   `diff /tmp/before.sql /tmp/after.sql | vim -`

Very useful for generating users migration scripts, for example.

Notes:

1. `--skip-opt` generates a dump with one SQL instruction per line, so it's easier to see the changes when you run `diff`.
2. `| vim -` makes `vim` read the output of `diff` directly into its buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Milo's answer is right on. I would add that to save you some trouble, download the [WordPress Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin. This plugin will add a little bar to the bottom of your front end pages and it will capture important debugging information, including queries made during the request. For it to work you need to make sure that the constants `WP_DEBUG` and `SAVE_QUERIES` are set to true in your wp-config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above I highly recommend query monitor plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/
It has a lot of great features and really helps with local debugging.

More professional tools to use are different APMs, but they come paid. The best one I ever worked with was new rellic, but datadog APM works quite good well.